# Cauchy Integral Theorem and the complex logarithm function

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, logarithms, cauchy-integral-formula, holomorphic-functions

I am given the following integral:

$\int_C {e^{(-1+i)\log(z)}}$

with

$C:|z|=1$

$\operatorname{Log} (z): 0\le \operatorname{arg} (z)\le 2\pi$

Is it possible to resolve this integral using Cauchy theorem? The function is not analytic in a line inside C so my guess would be that it is not possible.
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a little trick [using the contour integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_contour_integration#For_continuous_functions) formula
$$\int_{|z|=1}e^{(-1+i)\log{z}}dz=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\int_{\epsilon}^{2\pi-\epsilon}e^{(-1+i)\log{e^{i\phi}}}\cdot ie^{i\phi}d\phi$$

The contour isolates the point where the function is not analytic
[image]

Comment: Thanks the help. Just one question with this method you are using the parametrization of the circunference rigth?

Comment: Yep, exactly. $|z|=1$ is $z=e^{i\phi}, \phi \in [0, 2\pi]$ excluding the part of the circle where the function is not analytic.

Comment: ok thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Sorry but can you explain to me why this equality works i was trying to understand it but i cant make sense out of it why is the point in the circle where the function is not continuos ignored?

Comment: The point is not ignored. It's just isolated, so that the integration is performed on a curve, a big part of the unit circle, where the function is analytic. Then the result is extended to the whole circle using the limit, like with improper integrals.

Comment: ok thanks i will have a look at improper integrals and try to understand how it works

Comment: I added a picture, hopefully it explains the trick better. I am sorry for the quality of the image ...